# Logical algorithm for understand expression IF then

Tags: algorithm

i need to find an algo to solve this kind of problem:
Solve logic inside a sentence like

```
IF @1 and @2 or @3 or @4 and @5 THEN *STUFF
```

The request is:

0)Forget about "THEN *STUFF"

1)AND, OR combination can be any numbers, combinations,any kind of concatenate

2)can be also a simple one like IF @1 THEN STUFF.

3)OR has priority, this mean like @1 and @2 or 3@ always become, IF @1 and (@2 or @3), in any kind of combinations.

4)I need to convert this language to another one, and for now i have function like convertSingle(@n), convert OrGroup(List single), convert AndGroup(List orGroup);

5) i have full control on this side of code, so as long i can convert a single element and "concatenate" with the rest of OR and AND, i can write everything.

By now i use this solution, and believe me it's work, but i feel not good about that. It's not elegant,i feel this forced, and i wish to make this recursive but on my own, can't find solution for now.
This is my algo atm:

Starting from a general sentence like: IF @1 or @2 or @3 and @4 or @5

- it's collapsed, looking for OR in a regexp way, and it become IF #1 and #2
- saving what mean #1, #2 (it's just an OR group from prev collapsed) so

1#= @1 OR @2 OR @3

2#=@4 OR @5

- Then looking for *AND* and after last collapse this become IF %1 then..

%1=the AND composed by prev OR.

- i need a "special case solution" for simple one like if @1 then , can't fit inside prev solution..

In the end i have a working (for the test by now) solution. But i don't like that. I don't really know why, but this "step-collapsed" algo, mhmh i feel this not really good.
But by me it's the best i can think about.

I wish to know if others smarter people then me, can advice me for a better solution.

Thank you.

Comment: OR has priority? Are you sure?

Comment: yes i'm sure. I can understand it' strange in "math way", this natural language it's composed in this way by vocabolary. if you have solution with  AND priority , tell me, it's not matter.

Comment: Recursively dividing the expression is a pretty good way. You will basically construct a syntax tree. You will have single numbers on the leaves. So also an expression consisting of a single number should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to accomplish this. I want to post a solution for my particular solution, but maybe someone else will get the Pattern inside like start point.

```
private ApplyElementDTO recursiveConvertXacmlLogicPart(
        String collapsedlogicapart) throws Exception {

    /*
     * 
     * if string=@n return converted apply
     */
    collapsedlogicapart = collapsedlogicapart.trim();
    if (collapsedlogicapart.startsWith("@")
            && (collapsedlogicapart.length() < 5)) {
        return getApplyTerm(collapsedlogicapart); // this is just a term to
                                                    // convert
    }

    if (isThisJustanOR(collapsedlogicapart)) {
        return constructOr(collapsedlogicapart);

    }


    //
    String exp = "((?<=^)|(?<=and\\s)).+?(?:(?=\\sand\\s|$))";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(exp);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(collapsedlogicapart);

    int count = 0;
    ApplyElementDTO ApplyAND = new ApplyElementDTO();

    ApplyAND.setFunctionId(XACMLData.FUNCTION_AND);

    while (matcher.find()) {

        String thisAndoperand = matcher.group().trim();

        ApplyAND.getApplyElements().add(
                recursiveConvertXacmlLogicPart(thisAndoperand));

        count++;
    }

    if (count < 2) {
        throw new Exception(
                "Looklike this was the entire complex rule in recursion,"
                        + " but i can't find any suitable operand for AND. "
                        + collapsedlogicapart);
    }
    return ApplyAND;
}
```

offcourse constructOr call again this recursive for just converting the single term.

Bye